# I'm confused about parameter in Printf function

Tags: disassembly, gdb

I'm trying to understand call conventions and such. I created a function with the source code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int x = 9;
  printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

[image: and the output in gdb was the following screenshot:]

The above screenshot is its disassembly.

I have two questions:

1. Where does the `0x405044` come from?
2. Why does it store the contents of `0x405044` in the memory address of esp?

Answer (score 1):

0x405044 is the address of your format string. You can print the string  with `x/s 0x405044` It stores this address at esp cause its your first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what defragger said, there are few things to note (as you are learning about calling conventions). This is an example of 32 bit x86 calling convention (C).

- Before a subroutine call, caller saves caller-saved registers on stack (registers eax, ecx, edx - "if required")
- Then it pushes subroutine parameters on stack in inverted order (in your case, 9 and address of "%d\n")
- Then calls the subroutine (return address is pushed on top of stack)
- After return (return value goes in eax), caller removes the parameters, restores the stack and also restores caller-saved registers.

Now the I believe you got confused because of "42a" and "42e" instructions (mov). you must be familiar with "push" instruction - which is nearly equivalent to (sub esp, 4; mov [esp], reg32 - (this also affect flags unlike push))